# how to display pop up on another page on success of post method in mobile jquery?

Tags: jquery-mobile, post, notifications, popup

i am working on a project which is based on jquery Mobile. i am a biggner in this field, so sorry for the silly question. the question is -- i have a page 'Page1' and i am using post method to fetch data from database. On success i am showing a notification to user through a notification dialog(without cancel and ok button). now what i want this success message on another page "page2", and the message should be there up to 2 sec and then disappear automatically. i have tried

```
function sendAddGuest(data, dialog) {

    $.post("/GuestsList/AddGuest", data, function (response) {  //using the post method
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        $('.error').html("");
        hideLoading();

        if (response.result == 'success') { //if the process done


                $.mobile.changePage('/GuestsList/Index', { dataUrl: "/GuestsList/Index", reloadPage: false, changeHash: true });    //To another page "page2"

               // window.setTimeout('showToastMessage("Guest added successfully with window");',2000);  //i have tried this                
                setTimeout(function () { showToastMessage("Guest added successfully test2"); }, 100);   //and this also i want to show this message on other page "page2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also beginning with Jquery Mobile, based in the toy project I am working with I would suggest the following:

- Use popup from jquerymobile instead of showToast, then you could call
  the .close() of the element in the settimeout function.

This is the div you create for your popup (you put it in the page 2):

```
<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" data-theme="e">
    <p>Guest added successfully</p>
</div>
```

This is how you could call the function to open once in the new page (use the pageload event):

```
$('#myPopup').popup('open');
```

This is how you could call the function to close (in the same pageload event):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ $('#myPopup').popup('close'); }, 2000)
```

Sorry I have no time to code a complete example, but I think this is the way to go.

Hope this helps!:-)